# Rails mailer ignores attachment when using deliver_later with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, email-attachments, sidekiq

## What works

My current code for the user_controller.rb:

```
def create
  u = User.new(create_user_params)
  .
  .
  .
  if u.save
    WelcomeMailer.new_customer(u).deliver_now
    render json: u.as_json(except: [:password_digest]), status: 201
  else
    respond_with u
  end
end
```

The code for my Mailer is:

```
def new_customer(user:)
  @user = user
  attachments["AGB.pdf"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/files/AGB.pdf")
  mail to: @user.email, subject: "blaa blubb"
end
```

and its working like a charm.

E-Mail is sent with attachment.

## Problem:

If I change

```
WelcomeMailer.new_customer(u).deliver_now
```

to

```
WelcomeMailer.new_customer(u).deliver_later
```

I receive the mail, but WITHOUT the attachment.

I use sidekiq as job queue (config/application.rb):

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Comment: Now I tried to use `before_action :add_attachment`. but it's not used too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay...

noobish answer:

You have to restart the sidekiq-queues... Did it now after weeks an it works like a charm **hittingmyself**